# Browser history in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Why I use `browserHistory` in my React app, it still serves up a page at localhost:3000, but when it gets deployed, I get an empty page with nothing in the console.

When I switch to `hashHistory`, however, it runs fine on both localhost:3000 and on my site. Why is this happening?

The below code doesn't work when I deploy it (uses browserHistory):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Company from './components/Company';

const router = (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <StyleRoot>
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>
                    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/company" component={Company} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </StyleRoot>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    router,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I'm using v3.0 for react-router.

Comment: Please specify which version of react-router you are using.

Answer (score 2):

First, which version of React Router are you using?  In version 4, you need to create an instance of BrowserHistory instead of just passing the class.

You are probably getting the blank page as the fall back page for a routing error.   Check you browser's console for an error message.  You should be getting a default route for http://localhost:3000/badurl, `<Home>` for http://localhost:3000 and `<App>` with `<Company>` as a this.props.children for http://localhost:3000/company.

You can replace the blank page with a 404 page using `<Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />`.

Please update the question with more information if none of these help.

Comment: I'm using react-router version 3. I'm actually getting an error in the console now saying that resource can't be found. Something's up with my routing.